# Can I Add a CSS3 Transition to list-images-style?

Tags: html, firefox, css

I want a CSS3 linear transition for a "list-style-image". It will be for Firefox, so it will have "-moz-".

```
-moz-transition: list-style-image 0.2s linear;
```

The  above code does not work. Is it even possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Transitions generally only work on things where the intermediate steps can be calculated in a predictable way: colors or numbers (in px, em, generally). Images or binary style types (like display none/block) are either one value or the other, and have no intermediate values to use in transition.

Comment: Is there a way I can add a transition using, maybe, JavaScript?

Comment: The best I can think of is using absolutely positioned divs to lay one image over the other then fade that in/out with an opacity transition. The top image would have to be non-transparent, and the positioning might be a little tricky to get right, but it should be do-able.

Comment: @keithjgrant Actually, there is a proposal to be able to transition images with a crossfade.  It's just not really implemented yet.

Comment: @Boris Zbarsky -- Makes sense. I hope it gets implemented soon.